# Making the DocuSign API transition from sandbox to live

Tags: php, docusignapi

I integrated the PHP API for DocuSign by creating a sandbox account, downloading the php sample and placing the correct credentials in, testing (which worked as expected) and then ran through the live process of 20 transactions, having an enterprise account, etc. All was approved and everything seemed in order according to the admin panel, but making the changes documented in the go live docs just results in a server 500 error. Anyone else experienced this? Maybe some part of the live transition escaped me?

The code below should return login info:

```
// DocuSign account credentials & Integrator Key
$username = "someemail@somewhere.com"; //or the account string
$password = "xxxxx";
$integrator_key = "abc-123";
$host = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi";

// create a new DocuSign configuration and assign host and header(s)
$config = new DocuSign\eSign\Configuration();
$config->setHost($host);
$config->addDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", "{\"Username\":\"" . $username . "\",\"Password\":\"" . $password . "\",\"IntegratorKey\":\"" . $integrator_key . "\"}");
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// STEP 1:  Login() API
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// instantiate a new docusign api client
$apiClient = new DocuSign\eSign\ApiClient($config);
// we will first make the Login() call which exists in the AuthenticationApi...
$authenticationApi = new DocuSign\eSign\Api\AuthenticationApi($apiClient);
// optional login parameters
$options = new \DocuSign\eSign\Api\AuthenticationApi\LoginOptions();
// call the login() API
$loginInformation = $authenticationApi->login($options);
// parse the login results
if(isset($loginInformation) && count($loginInformation) > 0)
{
    // note: defaulting to first account found, user might be a 
    // member of multiple accounts
    $loginAccount = $loginInformation->getLoginAccounts()[0];
    if(isset($loginInformation))
    {
        $accountId = $loginAccount->getAccountId();
        if(!empty($accountId))
        {
            echo "Account ID = $accountId\n";
            // works as expected
        }
    }
}
```

Now, try the same thing using the live URL and credentials as suggested by the go live docs [here](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview):

```
$username = "live-user-account"; <--- live username or email
$password = "xxxxx"; <--- live pw
$integrator_key = "abc-123"; <--- same integrator key
$host = "https://www.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information"; <--- live URL
```

All I get is a server 500 error. I tried with just https://www.docusign.net/restapi and same thing. Server 500 error.

Is there some part of the go live process I overlooked?

Side note - this is attached to an enterprise level account

Comment: Which statement throws the 500 internal server error? is it this line `$loginInformation = $authenticationApi->login($options);` . Also can you login with your credentials in the Docusign Web App? www.docusign.net

Comment: Yes, that's the line. And yes, I can login. That's where I retrieve my username, which I use instead of the email. I tried email also. doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please share your accountId from the sandbox environment. I can look at our logs and see what is happening.

Comment: 3060232 - as seen from my dashboard at https://admindemo.docusign.com/billing

Comment: This is what I am seeing in our logs `One or both of Username and Password are invalid`.  Are you sure you are supplying valid credentials? Can you please try logging into the web app www.docusign.net and use the same credentialsin your api call.

Comment: Please reach out to apihelp@docusign.com if you issue is still not resolved.

Comment: So I found that using the live credentials, I can get the account ID call to work by calling https://demo.docusign.net/restapi initially. I can then set the base URL using $config->setHost($loginAccount->getBaseUrl()); but that still gives a 500 error. It looks like it is in the envelop creation somewhere that is giving issues. and yes, I can log in. my username and password are not wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so get ready for an idiotic ride....

Another stack overflow post answers this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43749389/docusign-what-to-set-host-variable-when-going-live-i-do-not-know-how-to-use-bas/43858402#43858402), but I will skip to the actual answer found [here](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client#usage)

Basically - you have to redefine the `$apiClient` variable by calling back the api with returned info...

```
$username = "xxx-xx-xxxx"; <--- your username string or email
$password = "xxxxx"; <--- your password
$integrator_key = "aaa-bbb-ccc"; <--- your integrator key
$host = "https://www.docusign.net/restapi"; <--- LIVE url

// create a new DocuSign configuration and assign host and header(s)
$config = new DocuSign\eSign\Configuration();
$config->setHost($host);
$config->addDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", "{\"Username\":\"" . $username . "\",\"Password\":\"" . $password . "\",\"IntegratorKey\":\"" . $integrator_key . "\"}");
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// STEP 1:  Login() API
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// instantiate a new docusign api client
$apiClient = new DocuSign\eSign\ApiClient($config);
// we will first make the Login() call which exists in the AuthenticationApi...
$authenticationApi = new DocuSign\eSign\Api\AuthenticationApi($apiClient);
// optional login parameters
$options = new \DocuSign\eSign\Api\AuthenticationApi\LoginOptions();
// call the login() API
$loginInformation = $authenticationApi->login($options);
// parse the login results
if(isset($loginInformation) && count($loginInformation) > 0)
{
    // note: defaulting to first account found, user might be a 
    // member of multiple accounts
    $loginAccount = $loginInformation->getLoginAccounts()[0];
    if(isset($loginInformation))
    {
        $accountId = $loginAccount->getAccountId();

        // HERE is where we all go wrong
        $host = $loginAccount->getBaseUrl();
        $host = explode("/v2",$host);
        $host = $host[0];

        // UPDATE configuration object and then re-call the api client
        $config->setHost($host);
        $apiClient = new DocuSign\eSign\ApiClient($config);

        if(!empty($accountId))
        {
            //echo "Account ID = $accountId\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Then poof, your envelope calls will magically work after that...

This is one FUGLY implementation of a sandbox -> live process. We got some great PHP sample for sandbox but then no connected real world examples of how you have to change things around in the live environment. Yes, we get that live can differ, but just leave this one small piece commented in the php sample and say "when going live, uncomment this" ... Literally nothing else in the code is different other than the login creds.

simple as that.

It kind of makes the sandbox pointless since I now have to re-test everything to make sure this live code is stable.

Thank you support for trying.

Comment: So, the only change is on the URL? What about the user/pass? On live, should I use the live user/pass? Or keep demo (integrator) user/pass? Thanks!

Comment: Honestly it's been so long I don't really remember but if you only have 2 sets of credentials it should be pretty easy to test that out and see